# Can anyone reccomend a plugin to create this kind of job board website?

Tags: wordpress, forms, plug-in, user-management

I am currently working on a kind of job board type site with Wordpress,which works by job seekers registering on the site, and job seekers filling in a form describing their job offer, which is then sent to users looking for jobs in that category as a message on the site.My question is, can anyone recommend plugins that can be used to create such a system or tips on how to do it? Thanks in advance for your help.

I already tried many membership and form plugin but at most they allowed messaging between users on the site.

Comment: This was previously posted and closed on [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/142441/46984). Should it not work out here either, you may be tempted to post it on the Wordpress SE. Before doing so, please keep in mind that questions asking for recommendations for plugins are explicitly [off-topic there](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), as is explained [on their meta](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1217/81949).